# Rearrage column order in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to rearrange column order in sql server ?

right now my column is showing like below when i physically right click and take properties:
in sql server 2005

```
colA1
colA2
colA3
colA4
colB1
colB2
colB3
colA5
colA6
```

Since i know these columns (colA5,colA6)  are created new !

How to make it like this ?

```
colA1
colA2
colA3
colA4
colA5
colA6
colB1
colB2
colB3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily enough in the designer (SSMS) - just drag the columns around to the correct order and then save - in the background it will script out and re-create the table.

But why do you need to do it?  Order of columns has no impact other than making things look pretty in the designer.

Comment: "Order of columns has no impact other than making things look pretty in the designer." -- it might make no difference to the computer, but we poor humans like a bit of tidiness & logical ordering, thankyou very much.

Comment: Enforcing this on any kind of decent sized database is this issue - if someone starts re-ordering columns in a live DB using the designer doesn't appreciate what happens under the covers of SSMS then they get a big surprise when the table locks up as it's recreated.

Comment: Note Mar Gravell's comment on this issue where the table is replicated as another reason...

Comment: @Chris W: Good point well made! Re-ordering columns in SSMS drops and and recreates the table behind the scenes. If you're at the design stage of your database no problem but if it's a live table with millions of records you could be in for trouble.

Comment: The best idea is don't do this - the order of columns should not be relied upon or changed; basic rule of defensive programming with SQL.

Answer (score 6):

Moving columns involves a lot of DDL, and doesn't actually do anything.

If the table is currently empty, fine... but if it has lots of data, this can be **very** painful. And if the table is currently replicated: even worse.

IMO, you should just handle this in the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT colA1, colA2, colA3, colA4, colA5, colA6, colB1, colB2, colB3
FROM   TheTable
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you just use a view based on the table to get the output you want? That's my first reaction.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the table, choose "Design", then drag the columns up or down.